# Material UI Dialog Component - How to show it?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dialog

I've implemented a Material UI table and need now to show a Dialog when user clicks on a specific row.

Bellow is just part of the code that ilustrates what I am doing. It gets the onClick event and calls the handleCellClick function to handle the event. The handle function should call the ResponsiveDialog, which is actually a snipped from the Material UI, but for some reason it daoesnt get executed.

```
export const OrderScoreCell = (props) => {

  const { score, scoreDesc } = props

  const handleCellClick = (e) => {
    <ResponsiveDialog />
  }

  return (
    <>
      <TableCell onClick={handleCellClick} lign="left">
        <LightTooltip 
          title={`Risco ${scoreDesc}`} 
          placement="top-end"
          arrow  
          interactive 
          TransitionComponent={Fade} 
          TransitionProps={{ timeout: 600 }} 
          aria-label="score" 
        >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

All UI you want rendered needs to be returned in the function component return. Returning JSX literals from a function only works if the function is called within the return, not as an event handler callback.

## Solution

Add local state that is updated by the click handler and conditionally render the dialog.

Example:

```
export const OrderScoreCell = ({ score, scoreDesc }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleCellClick = (e) => setIsOpen(true);

  return (
    <>
      <TableCell onClick={handleCellClick} lign="left">
        <LightTooltip 
          title={`Risco ${scoreDesc}`} 
          placement="top-end"
          arrow  
          interactive 
          TransitionComponent={Fade} 
          TransitionProps={{ timeout: 600 }} 
          aria-label="score" 
        >
      </TableCell >
      {isOpen && <ResponsiveDialog />}
    <>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Drew. Got it!!